# How to use Nodejs clustering with Sveltekit

Tags: node.js, sveltekit, node-cluster, sveltekit-adapter-node

How is it possible to use the Node Cluster module with Sveltekit?  In a classic node app, clustering is achieved by starting forks and serving the requests from the forks eg

```js
const cluster = require('node:cluster');
const http = require('node:http');

if(cluster.isMaster){
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
} else {
  const server = http:createServer((req, res)=>{
    // serve request
  })
}
```

However, Sveltekit does not have a single nodejs entrypoint that can be assigned to a cluster fork.  Sveltekit simply sends requests to each route as they come in.  The closest thing to a single entry point is the hooks.server.js.  Would this be the right place to create the clusters eg

```js
// hooks.server.js
const cluster = require('node:cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster){
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
} else {

  export const handle = async({ event, resolve }) =>{
    // server handle
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, Sveltekit does not have a single nodejs entrypoint

It does, in fact: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#custom-server

So when you build your sveltekit app with `adapter-node` you can run this entrypoint from a custom clustered nodejs server, just like you wanted.